Can the Pythagorean Graph be finitely colored?
Define the Pythagorean Graph as having nodes $a,b\in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 3}$ and an edge $a\rightarrow b$ if and only if $a^2+b^2$ is a square. After much searching I found the example in the picture, proving that the chromatic number $\chi$ is $>3$. Is anything more known about this problem? Could $\chi$ even be infinite?

The numbers in the example are as follows:

17089712640 - 555284201472, 357569372160 - 555284201472, 65554384896 - 555284201472, 1098884475 - 2865239520, 1098884475 - 4215208140, 2865239520 - 4215208140, 2865239520 - 5954748800, 5954748800 - 17089712640, 1098884475 - 35705292480, 4215208140 - 35705292480, 17089712640 - 37193013000, 2865239520 - 37193013000, 5954748800 - 37193013000, 17089712640 - 65554384896, 65554384896 - 357569372160, 35705292480 - 3016991577600, 357569372160 - 3028822917120, 3016991577600 - 4685210449920, 3028822917120 - 9610688102400, 4685210449920 - 9610688102400, 3028822917120 - 11618254061568, 357569372160 - 11618254061568, 9610688102400 - 11618254061568, 3016991577600 - 25555693363200, 4685210449920 - 25555693363200, 9610688102400 - 25555693363200


This paper shows that the chromatic number is infinite.

@mathworker21 Thank you. I think that domotorp is right, but that nonetheless your comment should be made into an answer, since its survey of known results is very interesting.

This paper shows that the chromatic number is infinite.
Indeed, Theorem 1.1 part (i) with $a=b=c=1$ is what you want.

I think this paper also addresses this related Erdos Problem http://www.erdosproblems.com/439

@dbal See here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/433095/2480 . I had actually forgotten that I asked the question there, and mathworker21 answered it back then too!
